# My flex row is displaying as a column and it's making me crazy

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I'm an enthusiastic new coder who hasn't fussed with building websites since my Geocities days.

I'm working on a forum skin and I want to display the staffers icons in a horizontal row above two information boxes.

I'm new at using flexboxes and it's giving me fits. I can't figure out why my row is displaying as a column. There are other problems with the code, but I can hash those out after I sort out what's going on with the flex row.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to get the result I'm looking for?

Codepen is here: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/boQgzV

relevant CSS is here:

```
#td-stfcontnr {
display: flex;
flex-direction: row;
margin: 0 auto;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}

.td-staff1 {
width: 350px;
height: 116px;
position: relative;
}

.td-staff2 {
width: 350px;
height: 116px;
position: relative;
flex-basis: 200px;
}

.td-staff3 {
width: 350px;
height: 116px;
position: relative;
flex-basis: 200px;
}

.td-staff4 {
width: 350px;
height: 116px;
position: relative;
flex-basis: 200px;
}

.td-staff5 {
width: 350px;
height: 116px;
position: relative;
flex-basis: 200px;
}
```

And here's the relevant HTML code:

```
<div class='td-banner'>
<div class='tdbncntnr'>
<div class='overimg'><img src='http://placehold.it/980x525'></div>
<div class='textblockhold'>
<div id='td-stfcontnr'>
<div class='td-staff1'>
<div class='td-stf'>
<div class='td-stf-img'>
<span class='td-imgrsz'><img src='placehold.it/200'></span></div>
<div class='td-stf-txt'><a href="STAFFER"></a></div></div>
<div class='td-staff2'>
<div class='td-stf'>
<div class='td-stf-img'>
<span class='td-imgrsz'><img src='placehold.it/200'></span></div>
<div class='td-stf-txt'><a href="STAFFER"></a></div></div></div>
<div class='td-staff3'>
<div class='td-stf'>
<div class='td-stf-img'>
<span class='td-imgrsz'><img src='placehold.it/200'></span></div>
<div class='td-stf-txt'><a href="STAFFER"></a></div></div></div>
<div class='td-staff4'>
<div class='td-stf'>
<div class='td-stf-img'>
<span class='td-imgrsz'><img src='placehold.it/200'></span></div>
<div class='td-stf-txt'><a href="STAFFER"></a></div></div></div>
<div class='td-staff5'>
<div class='td-stf'>
<div class='td-stf-img'>
<span class='td-imgrsz'><img src='placehold.it/200'></span></div>
<div class='td-stf-txt'><a href="STAFFER"></a></div></div></div></div>
```

*edited to clarify that I'm trying to make a horizontal row and not a vertical row*

Comment: Is `#td-stfcontnr` supposed to be `.tdbncntnr`? I can't find any element with the id `td-stfcontnr` in your markup

Comment: Your demo and code don't reproduce the problem you're describing.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError: oops, just fixed it

Comment: @Michael_B: let me clarify--when I look at my codepen I see the staff icons in a vertical row. What I'm wanting is a horizontal row.

Comment: That codepen only show 1 big image. Also, you should make a _minimal_ working code snippet, not post all your code. The same goes for the inline code sample.

Answer (score 0):

Refer to the [MDN flexbox overview](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes) for how to use flexbox.

A flexbox container can be declared with `display: flex;` and the immediate children will inherit this display as flex children. It's important to understand how the axis' work though. You can construct a simple flexbox row with:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap; // Row alignment, does not overflow to second row
  justify-content: start; // Determines content alignment along main axis (horizontal)
  align-content: start; // Determines row alignment/distribution along cross axis (vertical)
  align-items: start; // Determines content alignment along cross axis (vertical)
}

.container > * {
  display: flex;
  flex: auto 1 1; // flex-basis auto, grow & shrink
  width: 50px; height: 50px;
}
```

Comment: When using a property value (`start`) only being supported by Firefox you should mention that. I also don't understand why not using the proper one for Flexbox, so I suggest you read up on that